# In oscillometric blood pressure measurement, why do we assume that highest oscillations correspond with mean arterial pressure?

Tags: physiology, human-physiology, blood-pressure, measurement

As far as I've seen, the point on the oscillometric curve where there are greatest oscillations represents the mean arterial pressure (MAP). 
My question is - why? What is the logic behind this assumption? Or is it just an empirically observed coincidence?
[image]